# NativeWind not working when used with React Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation, tailwind-css

NativeWind it's not working.
It was working when the content of the file tailwind.config.js was './App,{js,jsx,ts,tsx}' but not anymore since I implemented the React Navigation.

tailwind.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./screens/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "inovarlagos",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.12",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.8.0",
    "expo": "~46.0.9",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.7",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.5",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

App.js:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

./screens/HomeScreen.js:

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View className="flex-1 items-center justify-center bg-black">
      <Text className="text-red-200">Futuristik Lagos- Home</Text>      
    </View>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

Project structure:

[image: Project Structure]

Result (TailWind not working):

[image]

Comment: Where's the setup they use in the docs? They style Views etc with their own methods. https://www.nativewind.dev/overview/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I assume you're using NativeWind, since support for TailwindCSS ended for React Native recently.

First stop the expo server. Then, instead of starting it with `expo start`, run `expo start -c` to wipe the cache that NativeWind adds and restart the server.

Source: https://www.nativewind.dev/guides/troubleshooting

Answer (score 7):

if you are using Expo, just put below code simply in your app.js

```
import { NativeWindStyleSheet } from "nativewind";

NativeWindStyleSheet.setOutput({
  default: "native",
});
```

Answer (score 3):

To fix this issue, simply clear your project's cache

`expo start -c`

or

`react-native start --reset-cache`.

Answer (score 2):

I've the same case as @epietrowicz:

**From**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./<custom directory>/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./<custom directory>/**/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

**To:**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./src/**/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I added an `app` folder to house my routes. I had to update my `content` entry of `tailwind.config.js` because the getting started guide I followed had `<custom-folder>` as a placeholder.

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', './<custom-folder>/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
// Change ./<custom-folder> to ./app (in my case)
  theme: {
    extend: {}
  },
  plugins: []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it helped to specify in the configuration all subfolders leading to the file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You also need to include the babel plugin

```
plugins: ["nativewind/babel"],
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is how I solved it:

1. Install the Expo CLI with `npm install expo-cli --global`.
2. Run `expo start -c` or `react-native start --reset-cache` as described
   in the [documentation](https://www.nativewind.dev/guides/troubleshooting).
3. If that doesn't work, make sure that the routes in the **content**
   section of your Tailwind configuration file are set correctly.

For example, the following configuration file will only apply Tailwind styles to files in the **App.js**, **src/screens** directory, and ***src/components*** directory:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./src/screens/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./src/components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
    theme: {
      extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so for me what worked was using a non breaking version of tailwind which is 3.3.2.

**If you already installed tailwindcss then uninstall it first**

After installing the previous version which is by doing

```
npm i tailwindcss@3.3.2
```

You should also reset the cache.

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Lord this wasted my 1 hour. Programming at it's finest.