# Tailwaind css in nativewind is not beign applied on Screen components

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css

Tailwind CSS  in the native wind is not being applied on Screen components.
Is there any package or dependency that is missing in my project .

This is a package.json

```
{
  "name": "first-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.1",
    "expo": "~46.0.13",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Tailwind CSS is Applied on App.js but on screens  components

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';

export default function App() {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

This is Screen Component where  native wind ( tailwind ) is not  Applied

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View className="flex-1 text-center align-middle justify-center">
    <Text className="bg-black text-white">App</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TailWindCSS not working on React Native Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73584046/tailwindcss-not-working-on-react-native-navigation)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly my `tailwind.config.js` Looks like this

```
module.exports = {
 
  content: ["./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./screens/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
   theme: {
     extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
  }
```

Then I CHANGED IT WITH FOLLOWING CODE. THE MAIN CHANGE WAS IN `content` part. By applying the above change tailwindcss started applying both in screens and components. This worked for me

```
module.exports = {
    content:[
    "./screens/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```