# TailwindCSS Certain Custom Colors Don't Work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, tailwind-css

I'm currently using NativeWind for a React Native project and I am having some issues with custom colors rendering in the project. NativeWind is built on top of TailwindCSS so I think the issue is the same as in TailwindCSS.

I have some custom colors in the tailwind.config.js file and most of them render fine in the codebase. However, certain ones don't render.

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./src/screens/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./src/components/MapComponents/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./src/assets/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontSize: {
        xs: "11px",
        sm: "12px",
        base: "15px",
        lg: "18px",
        xl: "20px",
        "2xl": "26px",
        "3xl": "32px",
      },
      colors: {
        gray: {
          base: "#e5e7eb",
          dark: "#69686D",
        },
        blue: {
          accent: "#0085ff",
          dark: "#5a49d9",
        },
        red: {
          base: "#FF0000",
        },
        food: {
          inner: "#ffc0c1",
          outer: "#ff6665",
        },
        deal: {
          inner: "#7ba8cc",
          outer: "#277bc0",
        },
        challenge: {
          inner: "#cfc0fe",
          outer: "#7446ae",
        },
        event: {
          inner: "#f09b72",
          outer: "#ea047e",
        },
        music: {
          inner: "#76ba99",
          outer: "#00ffab",
        },
        sport: {
          inner: "#F87070",
          outer: "#FE3E3E",
        },
        outdoors: {
          inner: "#4ABE21",
          outer: "#49AC26",
        },
        business: {
          inner: "#DEEE2B",
          outer: "#CEDD26",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Rendering a View container with bg-blue-accent, it renders the background color of that View to the associated custom color. However, bg-food-outer does not work for some reason. Along with others like deal, challenge, music, etc. I also have the tailwind extension from vscode that shows the css code for the tailwindstyle and in the code base when I type bg-food-outer, it shows the right css color.

I tried doing expo start -c to clear the cache but that doesn't seem to work either. How can I render the rest of the custom colors?

Comment: I have the same issue, and I follow this steps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73584046/nativewind-not-working-when-used-with-react-navigation#:~:text=To%20fix%20this%20issue%2C%20simply,native%20start%20%2D%2Dreset%2Dcache%20.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're using NativeWind, since support for TailwindCSS ended for React Native recently.

First stop the expo server. Then, instead of starting it with expo start, run expo start -c to wipe the cache that NativeWind adds and restart the server.

Source: https://www.nativewind.dev/guides/troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked this in the docs!